# Why does Flash use the entire height of a masked object instead of just the visible area?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mask

The problem is if I set the ***.mask*** property of a ***Sprite*** object, the ***Sprite*** object still returns it's full height when I call ***Sprite.height***. So I figured a simple way to overcome this would be to override the property getter.

Now.. even though that worked, if I add this masked ***Sprite*** object to another ***Sprite*** object, the new ***Sprite*** object will report it's height as the masked ***Sprite*** object's height even though I have overridden the property to return only the height of the visible area due to the mask. So it seems Flash ignores the fact that not all of the content is visible but still automatically increases the new ***Sprite*** object's height as if there was no mask on the masked ***Sprite***.

So I am wondering if there is a workaround so I can add this masked object to any other ***DisplayObject*** knowing it will be resized to only what is visible in the masked object.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Here is a code example..

```
var content:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(50, 100, false, 0x000000));
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
var mask:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(50, 50, false, 0x000000));

container.mask = mask;

container.addChild(content);

trace(container.height) // this should return 50 instead of 100
```

Comment: I've tried something like this too. Didn't work. Tried overriding getBounds too, that didn't do it either. I'd be interested to see a solution.

Comment: Is it a problem to setup the mask in such a way to be able to use it's height and width for the purpose? if(sprite.mask)...

Comment: I need to be able to add the masked object to another **DisplayObject** without it resizing it's new parent to the full height of the content, instead just resizing to the height of the visible content. I've already tried **.scrollRect** for anyone else wondering and that still returns the full height.

Comment: i have faced the opposite situation (3 days ago ! coding for my company all night long for a competition...)... with scrollRect not displaying the real size of the object... after seeing your comment i made a quick test (in order to check if i was dreaming at the time)... here is the strange [result](http://wonderfl.net/c/1lfQ)

Comment: Yes I already know about that strange delay bug. Apparently scrollRect doesn't change the height until after a 1 frame delay which makes it useless for me as I need it to update instantly. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for those interested I managed to come up with a workaround. What really annoys me is that **DisplayObject.scrollRect** doesn't update the dimensions immediately so until Adobe get off their arse and fix it, here's what you need to do.

The problem with **.scrollRect**, as I've mentioned, is that it doesn't adjust to the new width and height until after a frame has passed or after a certain amount of time. Either way I've basically built my class so that once **.scrollRect** is set, I create a timer that runs every millisecond, checking if **.width** and **.height** has updated to the new values. Once it has, I dispatch a custom **READY** event which the parent object listens out for before adding the class to the stage.

Now one ***very*** important thing you need to know about this arsehole of a property is that the object of which you are setting the **.scrollRect** property must be added to the stage before it makes any attempt at updating it's width and height values to those set in the **.scrollRect** property. So to do this as clean as possible, I pass the **Stage** object from my main class to the object whose **.scrollRect** I want to adjust, let's call it **MyClass**. **MyClass** sets its **.visible** property to false then adds *itself* to the stage. **Only once this is done** can I now begin my 1ms timer to check if the dimensions have changed correctly after I have set **.scrollRect**.

So once the timer tick handling function sees the dimensions have changed successfully, **MyClass** can now dispatch the **MyClass.READY** event to the main class while at the same time, setting its **.visible** property to true and removing itself from the stage. When the main class's event listener is triggered, it can now add **MyClass** to wherever it wants to, knowing that it will have the correct dimensions as set in **MyClass.scrollRect**.

This has been a great pain to myself and probably many other developers looking for solutions so I hope this has helped you and will suffice for now until Adobe does something about this. Thanks to everyone who posted previously who tried to help, I really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As xLite mentioned, it will update width and height when it rendered next frame.So you may do something to force it to render.

```
 var content:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(50, 100, false, 0x000000));
 var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
 content.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);

 container.addChild(content);

 new BitmapData(1,1).draw(content);//this line would help
 trace(container.height);
```

Comment: does that line always guarantee a forced render?

Comment: I have tried that in my work and it works. In most case, you just need call it once.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a direct solution, one thing you could try is this:

1. Draw the child (your DisplayObject that includes a mask and maskee) to a BitmapData object.
2. Parse through the pixels of the BitmapData object and check the value of the alpha channel using BitmapData's `getPixel32()` method.
3. Determine the bounding box that bounds all of the non-zero alpha pixels, and use those dimensions.

I'd wrap all of that up in a `getMaskedDimensions(child:DisplayObject):Rectangle` method.  Let me know if you need more details. Otherwise, good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks Ian, unfortunately that doesn't concern what I need. I am adding this masked object to a new **Sprite** as a child, now the default behaviour for Flash is to resize the **Sprite** based on the content _(in this case, the masked object)_. Unfortunately instead of Flash setting the height according the visible area of the masked object, it instead uses the full height of the masked object, including the bits that can't be seen. So I need a way of tricking or making it appear that the masked object is treated as if it's height was the same height as the visible content inside it.

Comment: I see.  You could extend the child object to override `get width()` and `get height()` to provide an adjusted width and height to the parent and trick it that way...

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I have already tried overriding the getters, Flash seems to get the height a different way. Thanks for the contribution anyway though. ;)

Comment: Lol, sorry.  I should read more :P  Have to you tried overriding `get transform()`?  I think I've read before somewhere that the `transform.pixelBounds` is what the parent might use in determining children layout, etc... Anyway, I hope you find it.  I'm interested to hear what solution you come up with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ian, unfortunately I tried it out but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

width and height can be overridden.  An object will always have an intrinsic width and height corresponding to what's rendered inside of it, and unfortunately that intrinsic width and height will never account for masked areas.  getRect and getBounds are not sensitive to masks either, so those aren't sufficient by themselves either.

What you'll need to do is write a recursive method named something like "getMaskSensitiveRect" that is sensitive to masks.  Instead of intersecting the result of getRect on each child object, you'd first test if each child's mask property is null, and if it's not null, call getRect on the mask instead of the object, and use that as the child's rectangle to intersect with the rest of the child objects.  And you'd definitely have to walk the entire hierarchy of all children, grandchildren, etc. to the deepest level to get an accurate measure, because if even a single mask is not accounted for, it could blow up the size.

Remember to override the setters for width and height, because altering the width or height of a DisplayObject actually alter's it's scale, and it does so relative to that intrinsic size, NOT your overridden width and height.  What you'd have to do in the setter is call your getMaskSensitiveRect method, and compute a scale using that and your desired width, then assign the scale to scaleX and scaleY properties.